# Page results in [database of your choice]

Tags: database, pagination

I'd like to collect the "state of the art" ways to paginate results for any database in this wiki.

Input: I have a huge table PAGE_ME:

```
create table PAGE_ME (
    ID bigint not null,
    NAME varchar(32) not null,
    CREATED TIMESTAMP not null
)
```

`id` is not necessarily in the same order as `created`. I want to display the results between `5. May 2008 09:03:01` and `3. Aug 2008 11:00:01`, 20 at a time, ordered by time, ascending (5. May first). The query should return `NAME` and `CREATED` (plus whatever you need to paginate the result), so the inner query is:

```
select NAME, CREATED
from PAGE_ME
where CREATED between '2008-05-05 09:03:01' and '2008-08-03 11:00:01'
order by CREATED asc
```

On the keyboards, ready ... Go! ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the paging queries from my [article here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2007/05/21/api-s-and-production-code-shouldn-t-be-designed-by-scientists.aspx) and for [sql server here](http://weblogs.asp.net/fbouma/archive/2007/06/05/sqlserver-2005-paging-there-is-a-generic-wrapper-query-possible.aspx). All queries are meant to work on whatever query you throw at them, so no tricks which work only in some situations.

Answer (score 1):

In Oracle a common solution is:

```
select NAME, CREATED
from
( select NAME, CREATED, ROWNUM rn
  from
  ( select NAME, CREATED
    from PAGE_ME
    where CREATED between '2008-05-05 09:03:01' and '2008-08-03 11:00:01'
    order by CREATED asc
  )
  where ROWNUM <= :max_row
)
where rn >= :min_row
```

Here, :min_row and :max_row define the limits of the current page, e.g. 1 and 10, 11 and 20, ...

Comment: I use this all the time. There's a similar feature in more recent versions of MSSQL so you can use the same construct (with minor modifications) in MSSQL as well.

Comment: Oh yes and you don't need the subquery in the middle, since you have the order by clause in the innermost subquery, you can just have the "ROWNUM <= x" thingie in the innermost one and get rid of the middle one.

Comment: You mean you don't need it in MSSQL?  You DO need it in Oracle otherwise you won't get the correct data.

Comment: Oops... Actually, you're right, you do need it in Oracle. I totally forgot that. Sorry for writing stupid things.