# how to repeatedly retrieve certain amount of data from a large data set?

Tags: mysql

I have a INVENTORY table. There are many items inside. When I query it, I just want to retrieve 50 items each time, and continue to get next 50 if user request and repeat this process until end of records. I am using MySQL database. How to do it in plain SQL if possible?
thanks,

Comment: How about http://stackoverflow.com/questions/909556/page-results-in-database-of-your-choice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM Inventory
WHERE whatever
ORDER BY something
LIMIT 50 OFFSET 0
```

gets you the first 50; the second time, use `OFFSET 50`; the third time, use `OFFSET 100`; and so on. It can be a problem if the table changes between requests, of course; if you do have that problem, solving it can be costly (force locks, make a copy of the table, or other unpleasant solutions -- there is no magic).

If your client just cannot remember the offset it last used, you can store it in a separate auxiliary table, but it does complicate the SQL a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`LIMIT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/select.html):

```
SELECT ... FROM ... LIMIT <offset>, <number>
```

In your case `<number>` would be 50 and `<offset>` would increase by 50 each request.